# Scikit-learn multi-label classification

Tags: python, scikit-learn, multilabel-classification

I am trying to learn about multi-label classification of texts using Scikit-learn, I am attempting to adapt one of the initial example tutorials which comes with scikit for the classification of languages using wikipedia articles as training data. I am trying to implement this below but the code still returns a single label for each where I would expect the last prediction to return fr, en

Could anyone advice on the correct way to enable multi-label classification.

```
import sys

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
from sklearn.datasets import make_multilabel_classification
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelBinarizer

from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.datasets import load_files
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.multiclass import OneVsRestClassifier
#change model_selection to cross_validation

# The training data folder must be passed as first argument - This uses the example wiki language data files
languages_data_folder = sys.argv[1]
dataset = load_files(languages_data_folder)

# Split the dataset in training and test set:
docs_train, docs_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
dataset.data, dataset.target, test_size=0.5)


#pipeline
clf = Pipeline([
('vectorizer', CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(1,2))),
('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),
('clf', OneVsRestClassifier(LinearSVC())),
])
    target_names=dataset.target_names



# TASK: Fit the pipeline on the training set
clf.fit(docs_train, y_train)

# TASK: Predict the outcome on the testing set in a variable named y_predicted
y_predicted = clf.predict(docs_test)

print target_names


# Predict the result on some short new sentences:
sentences = [
    u'This is a language detection test.',
    u'Ceci est un test de d\xe9tection de la langue.',
    u'Dies ist ein Test, um die Sprache zu erkennen.',
    u'Bonjour Mon ami. This is a language detection test.',

]
predicted = clf.predict(sentences)

for s, p in zip(sentences, predicted):
    print(u'The language of "%s" is "%s"' % (s, target_names[p]))
```

Returns -

The language of "This is a language detection test." is "en"

The language of "Ceci est un test de détection de la langue." is "fr"

The language of "Dies ist ein Test, um die Sprache zu erkennen." is "de"

The language of "Bonjour Mon ami. This is a language detection test." is "en"

Comment: `predict` returns a single class label, `predict_proba` returns the probability of each class label, is that what you're after?

Comment: Yes, though I probably don't actually need the probability of each but I'd like to be able to see the most likely labels rather than just one. For example the 4th example sentence contains both French and English so I'd assume it would return both en and fr as the labels rather than just en.

Comment: Does your training data have multi-label output?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [scikit-multilearn](http://scikit.ml) for multi-label classification, it is a library built on top of scikit-learn. With languages, the correlations between labels are not that important so a Binary Classifier should be well suited. You can find examples of how to do the classification in [documentation](http://scikit.ml/api/) but in your case what you need is to replace:

```
('clf', OneVsRestClassifier(LinearSVC())),
```

with

```
('clf', BinaryRelevance(LinearSVC())),
```

and at the top add the import:

```
from skmultilearn.problem_transform import BinaryRelevance
```

Just remember to install scikit-multilearn first!

Comment: Thank you for your advice, if I follow these steps I get an error on the fit- ValueError: Found arrays with inconsistent numbers of samples: [  1 476] I will look at the documentation as well though, thank you.